# textIsSelectable="true" not working in Listview on Android version preceeding Marshmallow (6.0)

Tags: android, listview, textview

I would like to be able to highlight text in the `TextView` that is in the `LinearLayout`, that is an item in the `ListView`. Android Marshmallow (6.0) works fine but anything else before 6.0 doesn't. I have tried setting `android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` that was suggesed on another thread but no luck there (tried with true as well).

The `ListVeiw` looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fff">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/list_of_selectable_text_items"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="@dimen/feed_item_divider_height"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:background="@color/background"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

And this is the list item's `LinearLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="107dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_text"
        android:id="@+id/selectable_text"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="May 19 at 9:35am"
        android:id="@+id/selectable_text_tiemstamp"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```